How to do dynamic upscaling using ESPCN?
I am currently doing 2x and 3x upscaling using ESPCN using pre-defined weights, is there any way that I can do dynamic upscaling, by changing the parameters/models/weights, basically anything?
I am ready to train the model by itself, instead of using pre-defined weights.
By dynamic upscaling, I mean that I enter the exact pixel value (larger side) to which I want to upscale and it does that (maintains the same ratio for shorter side).
I couldn't find any articles relating to dynamic upscaling, and need help regarding that.
